# Can I use a dictionary to decide which actions are taken depending on the value of a variable I call key?

Tags: c#

I am using this code to set the value of app variables depending on the value of a string called `value`

```
obj value = "abc";
var key = "a";

var map = new Dictionary<string, Action<string>>
{
    ["a"] = v => App.Helperval = Helpers.Utils.listOfDoubleFromString(value),
    ["b"] = v => App.SetVal = int.Parse(value),
};

map[key](value);
```

Is it possible to replace this part of the code with the following :

```
obj value = "abc";
var key = "a";

var map = new Dictionary<string, Action>
{
    ["a"] => App.Helperval = Helpers.Utils.listOfDoubleFromString(value),
    ["b"] => App.SetVal = int.Parse(value),
};

map[key](value);
```

Here is what I see when trying the suggested answer:

[image]

Comment: Can you suggest an answer based on your comments.  Thank

Comment: Use
map[key](); no map[key](value);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can init Dictionary with [key], and using `map[key]()` to call it

```
obj value = "abc";
var key = "a";
var map = new Dictionary<string, Action>
{
    ["a"] = () => App.Helperval = Helpers.Utils.listOfDoubleFromString(value),
    ["b"] = () => App.SetVal = int.Parse(value),
};

map[key]();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need to indicate the lack of parameters by providing `()`.

```
var map = new Dictionary<string, Action>
{
    { "a", () => App.Helperval = Helpers.Utils.listOfDoubleFromString(value) },
    { "b", () => App.SetVal = int.Parse(value) }
};
```

Comment: I tried this but I am seeing an error.  I will add a screen print to the question

Comment: @416 - Can you give an example of what you are saying using the code above thank you